# Ionic 2 Splash Screen can be removed?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was trying to make my splash screen animated and i found [this post](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/51/How-to-Make-an-Animated-Ionic-Splash-Page-with-HTML-&-CSS) very useful. But now the default splash screen can't be removed, I have tried all solutions on internet but no success. This is my Ionic version information.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.3
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the properties in your `config.xml`. For starters, add/change this property to `value="none"`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Also, try removing or resetting proper values in case of these properties:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="3000" />
```

Also try removing the plugin:

```
cordova plugin -rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your config.xml file it works for me

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

and also try to comment out splashscreen code from app.component.ts